# Why does Swagger mark the GET requests as duplicate mapping ke?

Tags: rest, api, http, swagger, openapi

I have this 2 `GET` requests one is `/report` and the second one is `/report/{id}`.

```
paths:
  /report:
    get:
      operationId: getReportsList
      responses:
        '200':
          description: List of reports
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Metadata'
    get:
      operationId: getReportById
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Report is finished and returned
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Report'
```

SwaggerHub shows an error against second `GET` with a description

> duplicated mapping key

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong and why Swagger does think that URLs with and without path variable are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new path where explicitly append your path variable `/report/{id}` for the second `GET`.